# Tell speck-mode to not highlight commands?

Tags: emacs, spelling

As `flyspell-mode` is [slow](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_spell_checker_problems.html), I use [`speck-mode`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SpeckMode). With LaTeX files, this mode
also spell checks commands. For example, not being an English word, `documentclass` is highlighted:

[image: Screenshot showing documentclass being highlighted by speck-mode]

*Can I tell `speck-mode` to not spell check commands?*

Comment: From the link you posted, it sounds like speck-mode has no documentation and is not actively maintained. Your choices are either to read the code yourself to answer the question, or find a spelling mode that has better documentation.